# R function not returning a value when accessed using Java

Tags: java, r, dataframe, return-value, rserve

I am using `Rserve` to connect with R from within Java. I have a problem with using a library function in R only when I am accessing it through Java. Here are the details:

In Java I have four `float` arrays. These are used as input for the `SpectrumSimilarity` function in the `OrgMassSpecR`package of R. To provide these float arrays as an input using `Rserve`, I first have to convert them to string arrays. Here is the code:

```
String[] consensusIMzString = new String[consensusIMz.length];
        String[] consensusIIntString = new String[consensusIInt.length];
        String[] referenceJMzString = new String[referenceJMz.length];
        String[] referenceJIntString = new String[referenceJInt.length];

        System.out.println("Filename 1: " + fileNameOfI + "Filename 2: " + fileNameOfJ);

        for(int i = 0; i < consensusIMz.length;i++)
        {
            consensusIMzString[i] = Float.toString(consensusIMz[i]);
            consensusIIntString[i] = Float.toString(consensusIInt[i]);
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < referenceJMz.length; j++)
        {
            referenceJMzString[j] = Float.toString(referenceJMz[j]);
            referenceJIntString[j] = Float.toString(referenceJInt[j]);
        }

        try {
            RConnection rc = new RConnection();
            rc.assign("generateSimilarityScore", currentDirPath.concat("/generateSimilarityScore.R"));
            rc.eval("source(generateSimilarityScore)");
            rc.assign("referenceJMzString", referenceJMzString);
            rc.assign("referenceJIntString", referenceJIntString);
            rc.assign("consensusIMzString",consensusIMzString);
            rc.assign("consensusIIntString", consensusIIntString);
            rc.assign("commonMassWindowThreshold", Float.toString(commonMassWindowThreshold));

            REXP distanceSimilarityValue;
            distanceSimilarityValue = rc.eval("generateSimilarityScore(referenceJMzString,referenceJIntString,consensusIMzString,consensusIIntString,commonMassWindowThreshold)");
            System.out.println("***" + distanceSimilarityValue);

            distance = Float.parseFloat(distanceSimilarityValue.asString());

            System.out.println("Distance value: " + distance);

        } catch (RserveException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (REngineException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is the R function `generateSimilarityScore` which takes these values and calls the `SpectrumSimilarity` function. This function should return a single float value.

```
## define generateSimilarityScore function
generateSimilarityScore<-function(experimentalSpectrumMz, experimentalSpectrumInt, referenceSpectrumMz, referenceSpectrumInt, commonMassThreshold)
{
  library(OrgMassSpecR)

  # Convert experimentalSpectrumMz to numeric dataframe
  experimentalSpectrumMz <- as.data.frame(sapply(experimentalSpectrumMz, as.numeric))
  # Convert experimentalSpectrumInt to numeric dataframe
  experimentalSpectrumInt <- as.data.frame(sapply(experimentalSpectrumInt, as.numeric))
  # Merge experimentalSpectrumMz and experimentalSpectrumInt columnwise in a single data frame
  experimentalSpectrum <- cbind(experimentalSpectrumMz, experimentalSpectrumInt)
  experimentalSpectrum <- as.data.frame(experimentalSpectrum)

  # Convert referenceSpectrumMz to numeric dataframe
  referenceSpectrumMz <- as.data.frame(sapply(referenceSpectrumMz, as.numeric))
  # Convert referenceSpectrumInt to numeric dataframe
  referenceSpectrumInt <- as.data.frame(sapply(referenceSpectrumInt, as.numeric))
  # Merge referenceSpectrumMz and referenceSpectrumInt columnwise in a single data frame
  referenceSpectrum <- cbind(referenceSpectrumMz, referenceSpectrumInt)
  referenceSpectrum <- as.data.frame(referenceSpectrum)

  # Covert commonMassThreshold as numeric
  commonMassThreshold <- as.numeric(commonMassThreshold)

  # Call the SpectrumSimilarity function which should store a numeric value in similarityScoreValue
  similarityScoreValue <- SpectrumSimilarity(experimentalSpectrum, referenceSpectrum, t = commonMassThreshold, b=1, top.label = "df1", bottom.label = "df2")

  return(similarityScoreValue)
}
```

The `SpectrumSimilarity` method prints a table with the results and a single distance value, on the console, when accessed independently in R, however no distance value is generated/returned when accessed through Java (but a table is displayed in the console, meaning that the function is working). Can someone help me find why a distance value is not returned? I am completely stuck here.

Comment: No one can run the code above since it's incomplete - you'll have to post at the very least the full result output - and ideally add `str(similarityScoreValue)` before the `return()` and post the output so we can see what is actually returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the R function in a .R file and call it from Java using R's source() function. In your code, there is no way for Rserve to know the details of your function generateSimilarityScore().